# unable to find jar files

Tags: integration, java

I am using eclipse and trying to connect to salesforce using java program

I am using import stmts like

```
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.LoginResult;
import com.sforce.soap.metadata.MetadataConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;
```

I am getting errors like jar's missing i am unable to get jar files related one's

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps outlined in this example.  Basically the step you missed was getting and importing the WSDL into your project, which will create the classes you are trying to import.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to integrate salesforce with Java:

1. Download `wsd.jar`
2. Download partner wsdl (common for all salesforce org) or download enterprise wsdl (for your organization only)
3. Then create class library using following command

   `java -classpath wsc.jar;JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc [WsdlFile] [output-jar-file]`
4. Now import created liabrary into your project and you will now be able to use liabrary.